# Failed Home-brew install on M1

Tags: xcode, bash, terminal, homebrew, sudo

I get this error after running :/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

```
==\> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==\> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/\_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==\> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R ruby:admin /opt/homebrew
==\> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 344d32bf7 Merge pull request #14368 from Kentzo/fix-cask-backup
error: 2535 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Error: Fetching /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

I updated xcode and tried the install again but did not get a successful install.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by running

```
export HOMEBREW_INSTALL_FROM_API=1
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

See [#666](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/666) for help what to do with git connection issues